# Java use String.valueOf(char[]) but shows garbled

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

```
char[] string = new char[16];
for(int i = 15; i >= 0; i--,input>>=1){
    string[i] = (char)(input&1+48);//ascii '0'=48
}
return String.valueOf(string);
```

use this way, will get garbled output as follow:

Input:

```
0
```

Output:

```
(will show binary square)
```

Comment: Do you know how the & works here `input&1` ?

Comment: What is `input`? Please provide a [mcve], with special emphasis on COMPLETE.

Comment: To the user who dup-hammered this, I respectfully submit that the question is too unclear to be a dup of anything.  Closing it as a dup enshrines it as legitimate, when it probably needs to be closed as off-topic or unclear.

Comment: Why do you guys close my question?

Comment: @JimGarrison You're right...I saw the array and garbled output and jumped the gun.

Comment: So it is not duplicated right? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I upvoted your question, please clean it up and make it coherent.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis about this Error:

```
char[] string2 = {(char)(0&1+48),(char)48,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};//Test
char[] string2 = {(char)(((int)0&1)+48),(char)48,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};//Test
System.out.println(string2);//Test
System.out.println(String.valueOf(string2));//Test
```

**When I write "(char)(((int)0&1)+48)" the IDE told me cast to int is redundant**

The Right Code:

```
char[] string = new char[16];
for(int i = 15; i >= 0; i--,input>>=1){
    string[i] = (char)((int)(input&1)+48);//ascii '0'=48
}
return String.valueOf(string);
```

Second Way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for(int i = 15; i >= 0; i--,input>>=1){
    sb.insert(0,String.valueOf(input&1));
}
return sb.toString();
```